# Iterate through ng-content in template

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 8.1.3 . This initial explanation is probably poor, but I hope the example will make it clear:
I'm trying to eliminate repetition in my code, by creating a new angular component. I want this component to place different types of content that is passed into it in different places, based on the type of content. I know I can do this with `<ng-content>` together with the `select` attribute. But, this following requirement is the cause of the question: I also want to wrap *each* content selector match with specific html.

For example, I want to turn this:

```html
<table class="visualization-control">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <app-input
     unimportantAttributes1
     ></app-input>
    </td>
    <td>
    <app-input unimportantAttributes2></app-input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <app-button unimportantAttributes3</app-button >
    </td>
    <td>
    <app-button unimportantAttributes4></app-button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <app-button unimportantAttributes4</app-button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

into this:

```html
<app-visualization-control>
    <app-input
     unimportantAttributes1
     ></app-input>
    <app-input unimportantAttributes2></app-input>
    <app-button unimportantAttributes3</app-button >
    <app-button unimportantAttributes4></app-button>
    <app-button unimportantAttributes5</app-button>
<app-visualization-control>
```

Notice that there are two rows. The the first row has two data cells in it, each containing an input, and the second three data cells, each with a button in it. But on different occurrences of this structure, I need a different number of inputs and different number of buttons. Note that the components that are seen by `app-visualization-control`'s parents should be the same instances that are seen by `app-visualization-control` itself, because of data binding. That is, I should not be instancing new components, e.g. with something like `*ngComponentOutlet` (to my understanding this directive cannot be used with passed-in component instances, it instances and destroys it's "own" components).

Below is my best attempt, but it didn't work: the content was not rendered, though no compilation or runtime errors were thrown upon visiting the page. Further, the correct number of `<td>` were rendered, but they were empty.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-visualization-control',
  template: `
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let inputTemplate of inputTemplates">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inputTemplate"></ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let buttonTemplate of buttonTemplates">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonTemplate"> </ng-container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./visualization-control.component.scss']
})
export class VisualizationControlComponent {
  @ContentChildren(InputComponent, { read: TemplateRef }) inputTemplates!: QueryList<TemplateRef<{}>>;
  @ContentChildren(ButtonComponent, { read: TemplateRef }) buttonTemplates!: QueryList<TemplateRef<{}>>;
}
```

PS: the example has been greatly simplified. In fact, I'm not even using `<table>`, I'm using ionic framework's grid system, but these details don't matter.

Comment: your `InputComponent ` is not `TemplateRef ` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need wrap the `ButtonComponent/InputComponent` content in `ng-template` then render the `ng-template` in `VisualizationControlComponent`. Because the `ngTemplateOutlet` cannot render component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjv3p4

**ButtonComponent**

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
  <ng-template>
   <button [style.color]="color" (click)="click.emit($event)">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
   </button>
  </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class ButtonComponent  {
    @Input() color: string | null = null;
    @Output() click = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>()
    @ViewChild(TemplateRef, { static: true }) templateRef: TemplateRef<void>;
}
```

**VisualizationControlComponent**

```js
import { Component, Input, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonComponent } from './button.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-visualization-control',
  template: `
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let buttonComponent of buttonComponents">
       <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="buttonComponent.templateRef"> </ng-container>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  `,
})
export class VisualizationControlComponent  {
    @ContentChildren(ButtonComponent, { descendants: true }) buttonComponents: QueryList<ButtonComponent>;

}
```

**Use**

```html
<app-visualization-control>
  <app-button [color]="'#e00'" (click)="onClick($event)">
    Button1
  </app-button>
  <app-button (click)="onClick($event)">
    Button2
  </app-button>
  <app-button>
    Button3
  </app-button>
</app-visualization-control>
```

Comment: While this solution does improve upon my best attempt described in the question, it does not satisfy a key requirement: that data/event binding be possible. After wrapping them in <ng-template>, the buttons no longer emit their click events. And the inputs' values can no longer be read. Further, these input and button components can now only be used as templates (e.g. through some mechanism such as ngTemplateOutlet), i.e. they can no longer be used as 'normal' components.

Comment: @habit You can bind input/ output and `ng-content`, the code and links updated now.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the previous comment, this solution has the downside of having to turn the components into templates (it introduces boilerplate whenever they would be used 'normally'). But, indeed it seems like currently this is the best solution for this problem (which IMO is a bit of a shortcoming on angular's part). [This post](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/) explains content projection quite well, and helped solidify my belief that this is the best solution

Comment: It also makes it such that styles cannot be added to these components through their parent component's stylesheets